# Set boot device / access console (Dell iDRAC 8) using modern Linux

Tags: dell-poweredge, drac, lom

I have a Dell PowerEdge R730xd which I can only access using the iDRAC 8 web interface. I'm unable to launch the Java (JNLP) virtual console, which might be necessary to fix the issue. I'm also unable to access the SSH feature of the iLOM due to some firewall issue I can't fix myself.

The server does not boot, as the first disk failed and doesn't have a valid boot sector, anymore. I'm unable to select another device in the web interface, apparently I require more permissions do do so (I am able access most other settings, though).

I have 12 disks in the system, and grub should be configured for most of them. The internal RAID controller is not in use (i.e., the disks are managed by Linux).

1. How can I select another disk to boot from using the web interface?
2. How can I access the console (via the Java virtual console) using Debian 10?

I tried running the JNLP using Java 6 to 11, and I also tried running avctKVM.jar directly (resulting in "access denied").

[image: Console preview]

EDIT (Post Mortem): Everything is fine using the HTML 5 console (see answer below). Bug your admin to enable it before you need it. I've been unable to use the Java console, but won't need it anymore. Selecting another boot disk seems to be a premium feature which mere mortals cannot use. I don't know why.

My best attempt for running the Java console (giving "access denied", though):

1. Take host, user, and password out of the JNLP file
2. Download the JAR files mentioned in the JNLP file
3. Put the two libs into ./lib (and unzip, place .so files alongside)
4. Fiddle with the security settings in `jcontrol` ("advanced" tab)
5. Run:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -Djavax.net.debug=all -Dcom.sun.net.ssl.checkRevocation=false -cp avctKVM.jar -Djava.library.path=./lib com.avocent.idrac.kvm.Main ip=HOST kmport=5900 vport=5900 user=XXX passwd=YYY apcp=1 version=2 vmprivilege=true "helpurl=https://HOST:443/help/contents.html"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the iDRAC firmware to support iKVM/Redfish which uses an HTML5 based kvm. Most manufacturers are moving away from Java KVMs specifically because of these issues. This was pushed along by oracle changing the endpoint java licensing for business.
Additionally you could try using VNC, but you may need to do something for authentication since the ports used for the remote KVM functionality and remote media are [documented](https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/uk/en/ukbsdt1/poweredge-fx2/idrac8_2.30.30.30_ug/idrac-port-information?guid=guid-84daf55c-3171-49fc-b423-cc870f508689&lang=en-us).

Table 1. Ports iDRAC listens for connections

```
Port Number   Function  
22*           SSH  
23*           Telnet  
80*           HTTP  
443*          HTTPS  
623           RMCP/RMCP+  
161*          SNMP  
5900*         Virtual Console keyboard and mouse redirection, 
              Virtual Media, Virtual Folders, and Remote File Share
5901          VNC**

* Configurable port
**When VNC feature is enabled, the port 5901 opens.
```

Table 2. Ports iDRAC uses as client

```
Port Number   Function
25*           SMTP
53            DNS
68            DHCP-assigned IP address
69            TFTP
162*          SNMP trap
445           Common Internet File System (CIFS)
636           LDAP Over SSL (LDAPS)
2049          Network File System (NFS)
123           Network Time Protocol (NTP)
3269          LDAPS for global catalog (GC)

* Configurable port
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm pretty sure those settings are not available at my permission level, though. I'll have to wait until Monday then.

Comment: The firmware already supported HTML5. However, I was not able to make use of that without waiting for an admin to configure it.